# Prove the correctness of iterative version of Mergesort

Tags: proof-writing, algorithms, computer-science

How can I prove that this iterative version of Mergesort is correct ?

```
def merge(arr, l1, r1, l2, r2):
    temp = [] #temporary array for holding the merge
    
    #since the two sub arrays are adjacent
    #the full range is given by the begin of
    #sub array 1 and the end of sub array 2
    b = l1
    e = r2

    #copy all the elements of the sub array 1 into temp
    while l1 <= r1:
        temp.append(arr[l1])
        l1 = l1 + 1

    #copy all the elements of the sub array 2 into temp
    #we do this because we know that both sub array 1 and
    #sub array 2 are sorted, so by doing this the next loop is
    #less complex
    while l2 <= r2:
        temp.append(arr[r2])
        r2 = r2 - 1
    
    #i goes from the begin to the end
    i = 0
    #j goes from the end to the begin
    j = len(temp) - 1

    #here we loop in the range specifiend by b and e (inclusive)

    #we compare the value from sub array 1 and sub array 2
    #if the current value of sub array 1 is less or equal to
    #the current value sub array 2 we copy the value and increment i
    #else we copy the current value o sub array 2 and decrement j
    for k in range(b, e+1):
        if temp[i] <= temp[j]:
            arr[k] = temp[i]
            i = i + 1
        else:
            arr[k] = temp[j]
            j = j - 1

    return arr

def sort(arr):
    n = len(arr)
    l = 1 #length of each sub array
    while l < n:
        i = 0
        while i < n:
            l1 = i #begin of sub array 1
            r1 = i + l - 1 #end of sub array 1
            l2 = i + l #begin of sub array 2
            r2 = i + 2*l - 1 #end of sub array 2
            
            #if the begin of the second part is
            #out of bounds we don't need to check
            if l2 >= n:
                break

            #cap the end of sub array 2
            if r2 >= n:
                r2 = n - 1
            
            arr = merge(arr, l1, r1, l2, r2)
            i = i + 2*l
        l = 2*l
    
    return arr
```

For the outer loop of `sort` I tought of one possible invariant

1. The sub array `arr[0:l]`, is sorted (which seems to be true)

For the inner loop of `sort` function I tought of three possible invariants

1. The sub array `arr[0:k]`, $k = i + 2*l - 1$ is sorted (which is false)
2. The sub array `arr[i:k]`, $k = i + 2*l - 1$ is sorted (which is false)
3. The sub arrays `arr[i:i + l]` and `arr[i+l:i+2*l]` are sorted (which seems to be true)

But I can't figure it out how to continue from here, or even if my invariants are really true.

Comment: Also try [code review se](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You need better variable names if you aren’t going to give us any comments.

Comment: Please give us a pseudocode version or explain in English how it works. We don't read code here.